# Log using NLog with Azure Devops

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, nlog, azure-web-app-service

I am using asp.net core with NLog, here is the NLog target config

```
   <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile-${shortdate}.txt"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        encoding="utf-8" />

   <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
```

When I run from Visual Studio (F5), asp.net create **logs** folder and generate file like above configuration.

But when I deploy to Azure Webapp by Azure DevOps, it couldn't generate log file.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: what do you mean "it couldn't generate log file", did it fail with an error?  Or was there no error and no log file?

Comment: Check if Nlog.config is deployed with the application. Check you have permissions. Check NLog Internal Logger. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: NLog.config is deployed. In localhost it can generate log and log file, in Azure WebApp with DevOps deployment there is no error and no log file at all!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the NLog.config to be included in publish. Update csproj-file:

```
<None Update="nlog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

The special one is `CopyToPublishDirectory`